# How can I select adjacent row in sql when ordered by a different field?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I've got a table of data with the following structure:

```
id |   likes
1  |     2
2  |     5
3  |     2
4  |     6
5  |     2
```

If want to find the row next to #3 I can use :

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id >= 3 ORDER BY id
```

However what I want to do is order by table by likes. When the data is ordered by likes it looks like this

```
id |   likes
1  |     2
3  |     2
5  |     2
2  |     5
4  |     6
```

How can I select the rows before or after a certain id when ordered by likes?
e.g. for id 5, my result would be row id 3 before and row id 2 after.

Comment: Why before and after #5? What do the `likes` have to do with it? I always find that writing out the reason for the selection in plain English helps to build the query. i.e., `Select rows 2 and 4 because like "2" is the median and I want the values above and below it`

Comment: The second output is totally confusing and not matching with your statement. Is that `1, 3, 5, 2, 4` in id column?

Comment: Question is bit confusing. Whether it should fetch the records whose 'likes' are greater than 2 or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If likes are unique numbers, following should work.

previous:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE likes < (SELECT likes FROM table WHERE id = ID) ORDER BY likes DESC LIMIT 1
```

next:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE likes > (SELECT likes FROM table WHERE id = ID) ORDER BY likes ASC LIMIT 1
```

You may change 1 of them to <= or >= and add `WHERE id != ID`

Comment: this is along the lines of what I'm looking for but in my case the number of likes is not unique.

Comment: @fatlinesofcode, Is it OK to suppose that current user is the best in same number of likes and show 1 random user with same number of likes. Or you need "if I after you than you before me" solution?

Answer (score 0):

Your second table shows wrong ids for the first two rows, by the way.

It should be:

```
id    likes

 1    2 

 3    2
```

This works in MySQL for me:

```
Select id, likes from (SELECT id, @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum, likes
FROM table u, (SELECT @rownum:=0) r ORDER BY likes) as derived  where
rownum >= 2 and rownum <= 4;

(SELECT id, @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rownum, likes FROM table u, (SELECT
@rownum:=0) r ORDER BY likes);
```

The last part tries to simulate the row number, which is missing in MySQL, but available in MSSQL, Oracle and others.