# Select adjacent rows in mysql – but when using alphabetical order of specific column, not numeric order of ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I have a wordpress install with custom post types where I would like to find the 'previous' and 'next' custom post type object via mysql.

I have read many questions/answers on SO regarding how to achieve this when using the ID. The issue is that a lot of these objects were input at different times, so their numeric 'id' order does not necessarily correspond with their string `post_title` order.

eg:

```
   ID   |   post_title
   7    |       a
   1    |       b
   3    |       c
```

The SQL query:

```
SELECT ID, post_title 
FROM wp_posts 
WHERE post_type = 'custom_type' 
ORDER BY post_title ASC
```

Gives me the results. If I know the `ID`, for example `b, 1` from above, how could I find that, when ordered by `post_title`, that the adjacent posts are `7` and `3`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I select adjacent row in sql when ordered by a different field?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17697826/how-can-i-select-adjacent-row-in-sql-when-ordered-by-a-different-field)

Comment: Isn't there a post_date field, why can't you just order by the date field?

Comment: @BrianDeMilia The reason is because I want prev/next based on alphabetical order, not date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with `union all`:

```
(SELECT ID, post_title 
 FROM wp_posts 
 WHERE post_type = 'custom_type' and
       post_type < (select post_title from wp_posts where post_type = 'custom_type' and id = 1)
 ORDER BY post_title DESC
 LIMIT 1, 1
)
UNION ALL
(SELECT ID, post_title 
 FROM wp_posts 
 WHERE post_type = 'custom_type' and
       post_type > (select post_title from wp_posts where post_type = 'custom_type' and id = 1)
 ORDER BY post_title ASC
 LIMIT 1
)
ORDER BY ID;
```

Comment: This didn't quite work, but this, and the related question above did help guide me to find the solution, I didn't realize that mysql could do < and > with strings, so the only issue with this answer is that I had wanted to sort by `post_title`, so line 4 should read `post_title < ...` and it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

How to alphabetically sort (orderby) the adjacent posts in a CPT. Could be DRY-er, but this is 1/4 as long as other solutions.

```
add_action( 'wp_head', 'projectprefix_adjacent_post_equipment_filters' );
/**
 * Sort Adjacent Posts (previous and next) in CPT alphabetically
 * get_previous_post_join, get_next_post_join
 * get_previous_post_where, get_next_post_where
 * get_previous_post_sort, get_next_post_sort
 * Ref: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/73194/64742 
 */
function projectprefix_adjacent_post_equipment_filters() {

    // exit early
    if ( ! is_singular( array( 'registered_cpt' ) ) ) return; 

    
    add_filter( 'get_previous_post_where', 'projectprefix_prev_post_where' );
    
    function projectprefix_prev_post_where( $where ) {
        global $post, $wpdb;
        $where = $wpdb->prepare( "WHERE p.menu_order > '%s' AND p.post_type = 'registered_cpt' AND p.post_status = 'publish'",$post->menu_order );
        return $where;
    }


    add_filter( 'get_next_post_where', 'projectprefix_next_post_where' );
    
    function projectprefix_next_post_where( $where ) {
        global $post, $wpdb;
        $where = $wpdb->prepare( "WHERE p.menu_order < '%s' AND p.post_type = 'registered_cpt' AND p.post_status = 'publish'",$post->menu_order );
        return $where;
    }


    add_filter( 'get_previous_post_sort', 'projectprefix_previous_post_orderby' );
    
    function projectprefix_previous_post_orderby( $orderby ) {
        return "ORDER BY p.menu_order ASC LIMIT 1";
    }
    

    add_filter( 'get_next_post_sort', 'projectprefix_next_post_orderby' );
    
    function projectprefix_next_post_orderby( $orderby ) {
        return "ORDER BY p.menu_order DESC LIMIT 1";
    }

}
```